# C# .NET Core 3.1 OData: unexpected change URI from https to http

Tags: c#, odata, put

I am consuming an OData service from SAP with a C# .NET Core 3.1 client and fetching data with GET and trying to send updates with PUT. The used OData version is quite old (2.0) and cannot be updated!

The service class (references) was generated with `Microsoft.Data.OData` v5.8.4 as "Connected Service" from the `$metadata.xml`.

After the service first used the PATCH instead of PUT, I was able to adjust the behavior with `SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate`, but now a strange behavior appears at the `BuildingRequest` event.

Although the protocol `https` is used in the `(DataServiceContext)sender.BaseUri`, the `BuildingRequestEventArgs.RequestUri` says `http` on every `PUT` and the `PUT` fails with error

> Request timed out

because `http` is not activated on the SAP server.

```
 :
 private void SRV_Entities_BuildingRequest(object sender, System.Data.Services.Client.BuildingRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        var authHeaderValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", Username, Password)));
        //this is where you pass the creds.
        e.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authHeaderValue);  
        // If I don't have the CSRFToken...          
        if( String.IsNullOrEmpty(CSRFToken) )
            e.Headers.Add("X-CSRF-TOKEN", "fetch");   // fetch the token
        else
            e.Headers.Add("X-CSRF-TOKEN", CSRFToken); // use the token
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CookieText))
            e.Headers.Add("Cookie", CookieText);      // and use the yummy cookie
        // token and cookie are set in the response of the fetch request in GetCSRFToken()

        // ############################################
        // This is a workaround!
        if (e.RequestUri.Scheme.Equals("http"))
        {
            logger.LogDebug($"Current wrong Request Uri: {e.RequestUri.ToString()}");
            e.RequestUri = new UriBuilder("https:",e.RequestUri.Host, 443, e.RequestUri.AbsolutePath).Uri;
        }
        // ############################################

        logger.LogDebug($"The Descriptor: {e.Descriptor}");
    }
```

Between a previous GET (always https) and the subsequent PUT after the entity change, the Uri is not changed and the DataServiceObject is not recreated.

```
public void DoIt(string findIt, string newValue)
{
    :
    SRV_Entities srv = new SRV_Entities(new Uri(ServiceRoot));
    srv.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password, Domain);
    srv.SaveChangesDefaultOptions = SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate;
    srv.BuildingRequest += SRV_Entities_BuildingRequest;
    :

    GetCSRFToken(); // <-- this is the part in "BuildingRequest"-event with the token stuff

    var dataQuery = (from x in srv.MyDatas where x.what == findIt select x);

    return dataQuery.BeginExecute(handler => {
        IEnumerable<MyData> datas = dataQuery.EndExecute(handler);
        foreach (MyData d in datas)
        {
            d.Value = newValue;
            srv.UpdateObject(d);
        }                            
        srv.BeginSaveChanges(handler => {
            result = handler;
            var state = handler.AsyncState as SRV_Entities;
            var end = state.EndSaveChanges(handler);
        }, srv);
    }, dataQuery);
:
}
```

With the "workaround" in the "BuildingRequest" event the call works as expected, at least without errors and as it did with "POSTMAN" as a test.

Is there a setting that causes this effect?
Is it because of the `$metadata.xml`?
Has anybody seen this behavior?

I don't like the workaround and am hoping for an explanation of the behavior and how to fix this.

Thanks in advance